# Processing nullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing, puredata

I have an error `nullPointerException` at the line `if (stringReceive.contains(tabStock[j])){` but I don't understand why there is an error with the index `j` of the array `tabstock`.

```
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;

String[] tabStock = new String[6];
String[] tabReceive = new String[6];
String stringReceive;
String oldStringReceive;
int cptEssai = 0;
int cpt = 0;

void setup() {
size(400,400);
frameRate(25);
/* start oscP5, listening for incoming messages at port 12000 */
oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);

myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",12001);

tabStock[0] = "1";
tabStock[1] = "2";
tabStock[2] = "3";
tabStock[3] = "4";
tabStock[4] = "5";
tabStock[5] = "6";
//stringReceive = "A3E8F6";
tabReceive[0] = "1";
tabReceive[1] = "2";
tabReceive[2] = "3";
tabReceive[3] = "4";
tabReceive[4] = "3";
tabReceive[5] = "6";


}


void draw() {
   background(0);
   compare();

}

void mousePressed() {

    OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/test");

    myMessage.add(123); /* add an int to the osc message */

  /* send the message */
oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
}


/* incoming osc message are forwarded to the oscEvent method. */
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
/* print the address pattern and the typetag of the received OscMessage */
print("### received an osc message.");
print(" addrpattern: "+theOscMessage.addrPattern());
println(" typetag: "+theOscMessage.typetag());
stringReceive = theOscMessage.addrPattern();
println(stringReceive);
if (oldStringReceive != stringReceive){
    oldStringReceive = stringReceive;
}
}

void compare() {
    println(stringReceive);
    println("compare()");
    boolean failed=false;
    int j = 0;
    while (cptEssai < 3 && !failed){ 
    for (int i= 0; i < tabStock.length; i++){

    while(j<6){
         if (stringReceive.contains(tabStock[j])){
         print("tag existe et bien placé   //   ");
         print("allumage de la lampe qui correspond à ce tag   //   ");
         j++;
    }
         else {
              print("tag n'existe pas ou mal placé   //   ");
              print("extinction de toutes les lampes   //   ");
              oldStringReceive = stringReceive;
         if (oldStringReceive != stringReceive){
             cptEssai++;
             failed = true;
             break;
         }
         else
         {
            if(j>0){
            j--;
         }
         }

    }
   }
  }
  }
  print("GAME OVER ! Désactivation de l'épreuve   //   ");
}
```

Comment: please provide a *minimal* example of the problem. you have posted quite a lot of code that is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: also, i don't see how this is related to Pure Data; while Pd might be the sender of the OSC-message, it is entirely up to the receiving application to correctly handle the message (or discard any invalid message). incidentally, what is the value of `stringReceive`?

Answer (score 0):

Either `tabStock`, `tabStock[j]` or `stringReceive` is `null`.

Print out their values before that line to check which one it is.

Once you know which one it is, trace back through your code to figure out **why** it's null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.    I made a print of `tabStock`, `tabStock[j]`   and `stringReceive`. `tabStock` prints something weird that I don't understand `[Ljava.lang.String;@1bc135b`, `tabStock[j]` prints `1` so it's good and `stringReceive` prints `null`. I found it's null because the compiler doesn't execute the `oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage)` function so it can't affect `theOscMessage.addrPattern();` to `stringReceive`. Do you know Pure Data ? In fact `theOscMessage.addrPattern();` is a value that I retrieve from Pure Data.

Comment: @Vince Nope, I've never worked with that library, sorry. The `println(tabStock)` line is printing the array's **hashcode**, since `println()` isn't smart enough to know how to print an array. You can use the [printArray()](https://www.processing.org/reference/printArray_.html) function instead.

Comment: Pure Data isn't a library, it's a software but ``oscP5`` is a library. I tried the ``printArray()`` function and it prints the array but now I'm stuck. So I will try to ask my question to someone who knows Pure Data and ``oscP5``. Thanks anyway !